# Error on ElasticSearch indexing

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to index some data from MongoDB to ElasticSearch but i got a error like below:

```
{"error":{"root_cause": [{"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"Unable to parse"}],"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"Unable to parse"},"status":400}
```

All my data are a string and array string on MongoDB and all my Elastic mapping type is text like below :

```
        'iran_code' => [
            'type' => 'text',
        ],
        'gs1' => [
            'type' => 'text',
        ],
        'international_code' => [
            'type' => 'text',
        ],
        "catalouge_link" => [
            'type' => 'text',
        ],
        "group_name_fa" => [
            'type' => 'text',
        ],
        "group_name_eng" => [
            'type' => 'text',
        ],
        "member_name" => [
            'type' => 'text',
        ],
        "brand" => [
            'type' => 'text',
        ],
        "whole_name_fa" => [
            'type' => 'text',
        ],
        "searchable_whole_name_fa" => [
            'type' => 'text',
            "norms"=>false,
            "term_vector"=> "with_positions_offsets_payloads",
            "analyzer"=> "positionPayloadAnalyzer",
            "similarity"=> "positionSimilarity",
        ],
        'whole_name_eng' => [
            'type' => 'text',
        ],
        'attr_keys' => [
            'type' => 'text',
        ],
        'attr_values' => [
            'type' => 'text',
        ]
```

Also, I change some data value while indexing to elastic

```
      $words = explode(' ',$array['whole_name_fa']);
      for($i=0; $i < count($words);$i++){
        $tags[] = $words[$i].'|'.$i;
      }
      $array['searchable_whole_name_fa'] = implode(' ',$tags);
```

So why the error shows while indexing?

Comment: Why did you call it "reindexing"?

Comment: because of first time indexing is done without any error, but when I change the data value from `whole_name_fa ` to `searchable_whole_name_fa ` while indexing shows the error

Comment: In elasticsearch "voca.", reindex means copy an elasticsearch index to another one, this is what you want to do?

Comment: I mean in fact indexing, I will edit my question

Comment: This usually happens when a field type get guessed by a record and then latter records do not have the correct type.

Comment: how can i fix it ?

Comment: no body can help?